# Installing Guzzle 5.x/6x Wihout Packagist or Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, guzzle

I would like to install the Guzzle HTTP client for use in my PHP application. However, I am not, for whatever reason, able to access Packagist.org on my development machine. I attempted to install the library using the git repo; however, I ran into a problem due the libraries dependency chain (it depends on guzzlehttp/psr7 which depends on psr/http-message, which I am not sure how to get outside of Packagist).

After a bit of research, it seemed as if I might be able to install an older version through PEAR. 
 Unfortunately, when I attempted to install through PEAR, I received the following error

> PS C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1> pear install --alldeps guzzle/guzzle
>   Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony.com guzzle/Guzzle requires
>   package "channel://pear.symfony.com/EventDispatcher" (version >=
>   2.1.0) No valid packages found install failed

I can use Composer, but not Packagist. I have looked into Composer's documentation, but based on Guzzle's dependencies, I have not found a way to load the package with Composer. Are there any other options for installing Guzzle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would work on getting access to packagist asap, otherwise you are going to have problems including any packages in the future.

I created a fresh .zip of and empty project with only guzzlehttp/guzzle loaded, this should get you up and running 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcns9rzd0lp013u/guzzle.zip?dl=0

Comment: Seriously, thank you so much. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This solution could work for you if at least you could go download something on pakagist.org from another computer and save it to your own.

Or

In the documentation of composer check for PEAR download this could be good for you as you will download package from pear and not pakagist.

NOTE: you will have to apply custom package like this for all dependency package Guzzle had on pakagist

Here a example of a local server serving a zipped copy of any composer package.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "vendorName/PackagheName",
            "version": "master",
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "http://myserver.local/mypackage/package.zip",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": ["."]
            }
        }
    } ]
```

It could be a local path without any local server in between you and your package.

```
"type": "path",
"url": "/~/mypackage/"
```

Check the composer documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) you have plenty of solution that could work for you.